# TFS Build- Deployment

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

I am trying to do a full CI-CD cycle using TFSonline.
when I go with 'AzureWebsite' along with Visual Studio Online, it provides me with a build definition using 'tfvccontinuousdeploymentTemplate.12.xaml'.

On check-in I get the output, the build triggers and deployment also happens to the azure website. The log contains build along with my deployment details, which is also reflected on the TFS portal
[image]

When I go the conventional iis route, I tried 2 steps

1. With Default build template and the good old ms build arguments `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:PublishProfile="dasd.pubxml"` this does the build and deploy but I don't  get the 'deployment summary', which is to be expected, because i did it via ms deploy...
2. I used the `tfvccontinuousdeploymentTemplate` and provided the build settings as the publish xml... well... build happens but the deployment does not

[image]

I'd like the build to contain the deployment summary for my deployment.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Does "2-" indicate you are trying two different ways to do the same thing?

Comment: 2- indicates my second approach to do a continuous integration and  deployment using the tfsvc template

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: @Jono_2007 sorry mate. I dumped TFSonline and went for TFS on prem, with InRelase( back then Inrelase did not have api's for tfsonline,assuming they have now)

Comment: I'll have to do some research into this InRelease. Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

TFS Online has since been replaced by Visual Studio Online and since by Visual Studio Team Services. The XAML based build engine has been marked for deprecation and will be removed from Team Services in the near future.

The hosted build controller has since been upgraded with build templates for Visual Studio 14, upgrading to the latest `tfvccontinuousdeploymentTemplate.14.xaml` may also sole your issue until the XAML build engine is removed.

The new Build Engine ships with a "Deploy to IIS" task and there is a 3rd party [MSDeployAllTheThings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rschiefer.MSDeployAllTheThings) extension which makes it very easy to pick up packaged Web projects.

Your solution to switch to InRelease has since also been replaced by 2 different versions of Release Management and the latest release management feature uses the same tasks as the new build engine uses. So it's able to use the same Deploy to IIS and MSDeployAllTheThings task.

**Due to the fact that this question is related to a SaaS solution, the old options are no longer available or will soon be removed**.